# Copy constructor and assignment operator in CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to locate examples of assignment operators and copy constructors in C++/CLI.  I have spent a lot of time on Google and surprisingly I can't find a decent example of something that seems pretty common.

Answer (score 6):

.NET semantics have no such thing as a copy constructor or assignment operator. You can define one in your `ref class`es, but it will be used only in the C++ side *if you request explicitly a copy`* For value classes, everything is builtin and you cannot override copy semantics.

Example:

```
public ref class Foo
{
    Foo(const Foo% f);
};

Foo^ f = gcnew Foo;
Foo^ g = gcnew Foo(*f); // This will call C++ copy constructor. No .NET equivalent.
```

Look at `ICloneable` if you want to implement deep copy semantics in the .NET style.

Also look [there](http://codeguru.earthweb.com/forum/showthread.php?t=390322) to get the different copy behaviors you can have. I'd strongly advice against storing `ref class`es on the stack though.

Comment: `gcnew`.  And the real "copy constructor" equivalent would take a parameter of type `Foo%`.

Comment: Well, the usage you have would be `Foo^`, a converting constructor.  `Foo%` would be for the copy constructor, used when passing or returning by value (or `gcnew Foo(*f)`).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Damn, you're right again :) To my defense, I must confess that I never write copy constructors in C++/CLI. Is there any use for them ?

Comment: Stack semantics (automatic call to `Dispose`) is pretty useful, but I'm not sure if C++/CLI even allows stack semantics for parameters and return values.  So probably not terribly useful.